# Liferay DLFileEntry Entity level cache is not clearing

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-theme, liferay-ide

I am trying to delete the images of the user based on fileEntryId from the DLFileEntry table by using following code

```
DLAppServiceUtil.deleteFileEntry(fileEntryId);
```

,But when i am trying to get the length of the user images by using finderImpl

```
SELECT count(*) FROM DLFileEntry 
 WHERE groupId = groupId_ AND userId = userId_ AND (mimeType LIKE "%image%" );
```

still it is showing same length,but after refreshing the browser I am able to get the  exact length so I thought there was a problem with cache I have used following cahce  methods to clear the cache

```
CacheRegistryUtil.clear();
MultiVMPoolUtil.clear();
WebCachePoolUtil.clear();
```

but still I did not get the exact solution

Comment: Can you elaborate on "the length of the user images"?

Comment: User have 5 images ,and deletion process working fine up to  4 images but if i remove last image then the user images length showing as 1  instead of 0 ,but if i refresh the browser page then the image length showing 0,I thought the problem with cache so i have used cache clearing methods but no use.

Comment: So the page says there is still one image, but lists none. Did I understand well?

Comment: yes exactly....